# Is there a way to make a struct take a variadic list of elements in a nested struct to be constexpr without initializing it in multiple parts?

Tags: c++, initialization, c++14, constexpr, initializer-list

Say I have this struct layout:

```c++
#include <vector>
struct A {
    char const* name;
    std::vector<char const*> list;
};

struct B {
    char const* group_name;
    A an_A;
    int other_stuff;
};
```

Which I initialize thusly:

```c++
B b = {
 "My B",
  { "My A",
    {{ "My", "variable", "length", "list" }}
  },
  42
};
```

Is there any way to define this so that `b` can be `constexpr` without having to resort to declarations of subitems before the main item?

Thought this might work using a `initializer_list`:

```c++
#include  <initializer_list>

struct A {
    char const* name;
    std::initializer_list<char const*> list;
};

struct B {
    char const* group_name;
    A an_A;
    int other_stuff;
};

B b = {
 "My B",
  { "My A",
    {{ "My", "variable", "length", "list" }}
  },
  42
};
```

But alas I get the following errors:

```
<source>:20:1: error: could not convert '{{"My", "variable", "length", "list"}}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::initializer_list<const char*>'
   20 | };
      | ^
      | |
      | <brace-enclosed initializer list>
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>:20:1: error: could not convert '{{"My", "variable", "length", "list"}}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::initializer_list<const char*>'
   20 | };
      | ^
      | |
      | <brace-enclosed initializer list>
Execution build compiler returned: 1
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/h3q45hMhr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **problem** is that you've specified extra braces around `{ "My", "variable", "length", "list" }` in your second example.

Thus to **solve** this you need to remove those extra braces `{}`  as shown below:

```
B b = {
 "My B",
  { "My A",
//-v--------------------------------------v---->removed extra braces from here
    { "My", "variable", "length", "list" }
  },
  42
};
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hjeoobjW3)